# How to get random generated class from/within an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I select the elements that contain the class my_class within the element with id = "info_id"?

Note that the element may also have another class, which I am not selecting for.

```
<div id="info_id">
    <span class="random_number">_blank_</span>
    <span class="random_number">_blank_</span>
</div>
```

I would try the following but as I do not know what the class will be, how could I accomplish this?

```
$("#info_id .class_name_goes_here")
```

but as I do not know the class name, how would it be possible to retrieve it?

Comment: "How do I get an element with a class I don't know"?

Comment: If that fits as a better title, sure.

Comment: `$("#info_id > span")` won't work?

Comment: Im unsure what you are trying to do:  You cant find a element for an unknown referencer.  With that said you can look for ALL those spans, and look at their CLASSES and then make determinations based on that defined set.

Comment: Does all the elements inside the parent have this class, are you looking for an element with a special position in the DOM etc. There must be something to go on, otherwise you can't select it if you don't know the class.

Comment: Why on Earth would someone implement randomizing the classnames?

Comment: Why would you not know the class?

Comment: The reason I do not know the class name is because it's an table id retrieved from the database, I am trying to use the .click function to show specific information for each of it's tables, and the only way to connect both the id row's with the information is by using random id's, in this case I found better to use the class which is actually the incremented id from the database.

Comment: they arent random in this case.  There *IS* meaning to the data.

Comment: @iBrazilian2 Wow. That is a *completely different problem* than the one posted.

Comment: @iBrazilian2, it appears you've asked an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about what you think might be a solution, try asking about your **actual problem** instead.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you know the class name and it's stored in a variable?

`$("#info_id ." + className)`

Comment: "- How do I get an element with a class I don't know? - If that fits as a better title, sure. - I assume you know the class name and it's stored in a variable?" Well...

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the class of the element you're selecting for (as you've said, it's an `id` from the database), then you're right out of luck.  You'd stand a better chance changing the code that generates said classes.

If the HTML is *exactly* like what you have in your question, then you can select via element, finding the class that way:

```
var myClass = $("#info_id span").attr('class')
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like the class should belong in the data portion of code:

```
<span data-tableid="_randomNumber_">TEST</span>
```

That way there wont be addidional strings mixed in there.  Then you can do requests like:

```
$("div#info_id > span").on("click", function(e){
    var tblId = $(this).data("tableid");
    //do ajax request against it or whatever parsing you might need
});
```

also:

```
var classArray = $("div#info_id > span").map(function(){
    return $(this).attr("class")
});
```

This will return an array containing all the classes in the scope you are looking for.  You can then narrow that.  or use other jquery things.  Filter might have some uses here.